# Using Yeoman/Brunch/Grunt inside of an Express.js project

Tags: express, structure, gruntjs, yeoman, brunch

I am wondering how I should structure the front-end of my Express.js project.

I haven't done much with Grunt before, but I understand that it performs tasks such as compiling, and then saves the result.

Currently, my Express.js project looks like this:

```
/app
    /models
    /controllers
    /views
/config
/public
```

Any files inside of `/public` are static and served as such by the Node app. So, do I initialise Yeoman/Brunt inside of here, or should I store my source outside of the document root, and instead just have it compile to `/public`? If so, where would you recommend the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yeoman team have setup an [express dedicated project](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/tree/express-stack) which answers this question in the form of back-end generators.

Answer (score 3):

If you will init brunch project, it’s recommended to do it outside `public` dir and make it compile stuff to `public` dir. You can integrate brunch with express: start your express server with `brunch watch --server` quite simply: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/453